# Git credential manager to store credential from salsa.debian.org

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I am cloning multiple repositories from salsa.debian.org, I am wondering how I can use git credential manager to store the password for this site?

Every 100 or so repositories that I clone, it will prompt me for passwords, how can I avoid typing in the password manually?

```
Username for 'https://salsa.debian.org':
Password for 'https://abc@salsa.debian.org'
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you. I am very new to git credential manager.